# Excel not responding when value not found

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

A 1004 error arises at the line

```
Loop Until Cells(c, 1) Like "*" & ISIN & "*"
```

The loop is supposed to find a number and go to the next iteration in the loop if a number is not there.

The error arises because the ISIN is not found.
I am not sure where to insert `On Error Resume Next` in my code.

Seems to be a problem with the second `Do Loop`.

```vb
    Dim a, b, c As Double
    Dim WS1, WS2 As String
    Dim ISIN As String

    WS1 = "1M_issues"
    WS2 = "MI_1"

    Sheets(WS2).Select
    Range("a1").Select

    'Count ISINs to find
    a = 1
    Do
        a = a + 1
    Loop Until Cells(a + 1, 1) = ""

    'Choose ISIN
    For b = 2 To a
        ISIN = Sheets(WS2).Cells(b, 1)

        'Find ISIN within cells (looping)
        Sheets(WS1).Select
        c = 1
        Do
            c = c + 1
        Loop Until Cells(c, 1) Like "*" & ISIN & "*"
        
        'Copy CR from general_report to target sheet
        Sheets(WS2).Cells(b, 2) = Sheets(WS1).Cells(c, 3)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, simple question:  What happens if `ISIN` **doesn't** appear in Column A of the 1M_issues sheet?  An infinite loop, which will crash Excel! Try  `rTMP = Sheets(WS1).Find(ISIN, lookAt:=xlWhole): If Not rTMP Is Nothing Then Sheets(WS2).Cells(b, 2).Value = rTMP.Offset(0,2).Value` ?  Or, even, `Sheets(WS2).Cells(b,2).Value = Application.VLookup("*" & ISIN & "*",Sheets(WS3).Columns("A:C"),3,False)`?

Comment: `On error Resume Next` doesn't crash Excel. It just hides runtime errors (but they happen anyway!). Unless you know exactly what you are doing, forget about Resume Next. That said: What do you mean with "Crashing"? Excel crashed and quits? Or you get a Runtime Error? If the latter: What is the error message? What is the value of `c` at that moment? What is the content of the cell at that moment?

Comment: Without ```On error Resume Next``` the macro gets an 1004 Error. With it Excel ends up not responding.

Comment: It probably ends up not responding because the ISIN is not found and it loops until forever. And the 1004 raises up when end of the sheet is reached and the address gets invalid.

Comment: I should have clarified that is what is happening. I just am not able move to the next ISIN after and it ends with the error.

Comment: You need to deal with the case that a number cannot be found. That simple.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thought ```On error Resume Next``` could be used but see that it can not. Thanks.

Comment: @SozDaneron "Not found, moving to the next" isn't an error so far as VBA is concerned.  You want something like `Loop Until (Cells(c, 1) Like "*" & ISIN & "*") Or (c>UsedRange.Rows.Count)` to limit the number of rows that it looks at.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @chronocidal and @FunThomas. I have opted for `Loop Until Cells(c, 1) Like "*" & ISIN & "*" Or (Cells(c, 1) = "")`. I realize it is not the most elegant solution and I will probably return to improve upon this later, but for the moment it is working.